# Visual Studio Code IDE splitting screen in same file (not wanted)

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, scroll, ide, screen

I have an weird issue with Visual Studio Code.
I didn't split the screen, not collapsed some lines of code.
Nevertheless, when I scroll down, there is some random line that gets fixed and screen gets divided by that.

[image]

top code fixed, bottom conde scrollable.

How can I undo this effect ??

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vs code,

- STEP 1: Go to settings
- STEP 2: Search **Sticky** on search bar
- STEP 3: Uncheck Enable scrolling of Sticky Scroll with the
  editor's horizontal scrollbar.

For more Info Visit here [Sticky_Scroll](https://dev.to/bytehide/visual-studio-codes-new-editor-sticky-scroll-feature-never-get-lost-in-the-code-again-1dob)

Comment: Thank you !!
I had to uncheck almost everything to have some effect
No idea on how that went there
Thank you very much !!